# Blocking Arbitrary Elements from Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy

Is there any way to block specific HTML elements from being created into an IFrame?

I'm not using JQuery but I don't mind using it.

My base code is like:

```
<iframe id="id_frame_01" src="somepage"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript>

frame = document.getElementById('id_frame_01').contentWindow.document;

frame.onload = function(){
    var toremove = frame.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    toremove.outerHTML = '';
    toremove = frame.getElementsByTagName('object');
    toremove.outerHTML = '';
}

</script>
```

I have full access to the content of the iframe, but if I try to remove the elements manually after the onload event, the onload event is way too far and the (example) YouTube video starts playing.

I know the IDs of the elements to remove, but I prefer not to use them because a website "update" can break the system.
Instead I prefer to filter by elements type.

It is a browser-specific page, Chrome-only.

Is there a way to attach an onchange event to a non-created element?

Is there a way to intercept the loading of the elements?

Comment: It *might* be possible to do something with the tricks that [the x-tags project](http://x-tags.org/index) uses.

Comment: In fact I found out I can use  `frame.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",function(){...})`, even if in fact I indirectly discovered that on the x-tags project page. Thank you, then!

Comment: Note that events such as DOMNodeInserted are deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference

Comment: Ok, will take it into consideration, so I'm still looking for some kind of answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the page directly in an iframe, you could use ajax (or $.ajax with jQuery). This would allow you to filter the page html and inject only the content you want your users to see.

You say you have full access to the iframe content, so I am assuming your implementation follows the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: It does, as I put allow-same-origin in the tag list. Seems like a good idea anyways, even if I will have to do more "playing" to remove manually the elements from the HTML code. I like lower-level works anyways. In case I don't get any other answer within a couple days I will try to remember to mark yours as best answer.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery $.load, which would allow you to select the element you want (rather than filtering out the ones you don't want).

Comment: The page sadly changes a lot of times, and with it also the inner elements do change id, type and such. I think I will stick to the only answer.